# Getting SVN 1.6/1.7 on Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, yum, subversion

I have a remote repository which is running 1.6 that I have no admin rights to, thus I'm trying to install a version of SVN that is compatible with 1.6.

Doing a `yum --showduplicates list subversion` shows me that there is only 1.8 available in the repository.

Can anyone provide some pointers as to how I can get SVN 1.6/1.7 on Fedora 20? The only thing that I can find for SVN 1.6/1.7 seems to be the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to grab the RPMs for Fedora 19 that were at 1.7 from the Koji build system.

- http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=752

You'll have to manually download all the corresponding packages that Subversion depends on and manually install them using `yum`:

```
$ sudo yum localinstall <pkg1> <pkg2>
```

You'll likely need to remove the other packages prior.